# Error al perder referencia con la promesa

Tags: javascript, promesas, net, tcpip

requiero saber si esto es posible, Actualmente estoy intentando realizar un ping a un servidor que tenemos, pero requiero hacerlo por JS. Instale Socket en mi libreria y estoy probando, pero al realizar una funcion con setInterval al momento de volver a resolver la promesa, pierde su valor y he intentado almacenarla de varias forma pero no me lo permite. Quisiera que me ayuden para validar como pudiera hacer este ejercicio.

server.js

```
const net = require("net");

const server = net.createServer();


server.on("connection", (socket) => {

    socket.on("data", (data) => {

        console.log("\nConnection Successfull: " + data);
        console.log("Aqui deberia almacenar la variable data " + data);
        setInterval(() => {
            //var data = null;
            //var data = "190.40.199.151";
            data = new Promise((res, rej) => {
                if (data === null) {
                    rej("Server ip not detected [WARNING]!")
                } else {
                    res("successful ping to ip  " + data);
                }
            })
            data.then((res) => {
                JSON.stringify((console.log("\nAqui no deberia perder la referencia " + res)))
                console.log("\nAqui esta la info" + info)
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
            })
            console.log("\nAqui esta el final" + data);
        }, 1000)

    })

    socket.on("error", (err) => {
        console.log(err.message)
    })
})

server.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("Server listening on port", server.address().port)
})
```

Client.js

```
const net = require("net");
const readline = require("readline-sync");

const options = {
    port: 4000,
    host: "127.0.0.1"
}

const client = net.createConnection(options);

client.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("connection sucessful!!");
    sendLine();
})

client.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log(err.message)
})

function sendLine() {
    var ip = readline.question("\nIntroduce la ip del servidor: ")
    if (ip !== "190.40.199.151") {
        console.log("this ip is inccorect")
    } else {
        client.write(ip);
    }
}
```

Comment: Recibes un parámetro con el nombre `data` y lo sobrescribes al crear la promesa y, dentro, también tratas de acceder a esa variable. Lo primero sería cambiar el nombre de variable para la promesa y definirla con `let`, para que solo exista en el contexto donde se definió.

Comment: No tiene sentido intentar querer hacer ping a un servidor mediante `nodejs` o por lo menos yo no le veo mucho sentido ya que para eso esta la terminal, la pregunta es... para que quisieras hacerle ping internamente al server?, es mejor comprobarlo desde terminal para no tener que instalar otro tipo de cosas solo para tener que hacer un simple ping. lo otro es que recuerda que una promesa es un objeto asincrono y lo que tratas de hacer con ese `setInterval` no es valido, eso jamas te funcionara.

Comment: Hola Riven, lo que deseo es monitorear el Ping de un servidor desde mi cliente, se que hay formas mejores de hacerlos, inclusos servicios cmo Zabbix,, que hasta puedo validar el filesystem, pero tenemos un cliente que sufre mucho de perdida de energia y queriamos ver si ponemos en practica un poco la programacion para realizar este tipo de peticiones. Lo que dices es valido, pero Quiero saber si se puede realizar este tipo de ejercicios con programacion.

Comment: @Triby Hola Triby muchas gracias me ayudo, hice lo que me comentaste defini en el scope de la promesa con let cambiandole el nombre de la varia con let ip = new Promise y funciono. aun me falta enviar crear en el ambiente del servidor este script y probarlo. por que todas las pruebas las estoy haciendo en el entorno local